# build.gradle del proyecto

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Este cambio en el build.gradle del proyecto:

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

es muy diferente al que conocía en versiones anteriores del IDE:

```
 allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
  }
}
```

¿donde y cómo he de añadir en la última versión del build.gradle del proyecto los repositorios maven(), google(), etc...? ¿Para qué ha quedado éste fichero?

Answer (score 0):

Las dependencias deben ser agregadas en el archivo `build.gradle`, pero el que se encuentra dentro del directorio `app/`:

[image: Android Studio Jorgesys build.gradle]